# Regex: Get group inside another group. These groups have same characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am building a regex pattern that runs in JavaScript.

```
Regex pattern: /A[\s\S]*Z/g  
Content: ABZABCZ
```

I want to get two groups: `ABZ` and `ABCZ` 
Currently, I only get a first almost group: `ABZABCZ`

Do we have any solution for this case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the pattern [non greedy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers), using `[\s\S]*?`

```js
const re = /A[\s\S]*?Z/g
console.log('ACZABCZ'.match(re))
```